# How to tell when client is done sending image

Tags: python, sockets

I am creating a file server in python using ftp sockets where multiple clients send images to a server. This is the method I am using to receive the image on the server side:

```
while True:
    data = client.recv(512)
    if not data:
        break
    file.write(data)
```

And this is the method I am using to send the image to the server:

```
while True:
    data = file.read(512)
    if not data:
        break
    server.send(data)
```

The problem I am running into is that on the server side the while loop is never exited which means the code is either stuck in the recv call or the if statement is never true. On the client side there are no problems, the loop is exited properly. I've heard that the client side will send something to the server to tell it to stop but the if statement doesn't seem to pick it up. How can I get the server to stop trying to receive without closing the connection?

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.python.org/2/howto/sockets.html#disconnecting

On the client, close the socket to the server. On the server, check whether the recv returned 0 bytes.

Also from the [documentation for using a socket](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/sockets.html#using-a-socket):

> When a recv returns 0 bytes, it means the other side has closed (or is
>   in the process of closing) the connection. You will not receive any
>   more data on this connection. Ever. You may be able to send data
>   successfully; I’ll talk more about this later.

Comment: How would I check for 0 bytes?

Comment: @JackHipson300 one of `data == ''` or `len(data) == 0`

Comment: That still doesn't work. The if statement doesnt even run after the client is done sending, its just stuck in recv

Comment: This method didn't work as the if statement wouldn't run it would just get stuck in recv. But I was able to fix it by sending in the filesize and breaking out of the loop when the filesize was met.

Answer (score 0):

Data will never be nothing unless the client closes the connection.

```
server.close()
```